# dash dynamically generating graphs in tabs

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a dropdown list of Indian states.
 Upon selecting one state, different graphs should be generated under different tabs.
 I want to generate a total of 6 graphs and 3 tabs namely, 'convicts', 'under_trial', 'detenues'.
 Each of these tabs will contain 2 graphs each.
The graphs are

gender and caste distribution of convicts

gender and caste distribution of under_trial

gender and caste distribution of detenues 
 based on the dropdown value of the Indian state selected.

[image]

I want to create something like this.

Here is the [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/rajanand/prison-in-india?select=Caste.csv) used.

Libraries imported

```
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
```

Dash web app initialization

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
```

Pandas dataframe loading

```
df = pd.read_csv("Caste.csv")
```

Defined dropdown and graph functions

```
def dropdown():
    return html.Div([dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown',
                                  options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df["state_name"].unique()],
                                  value="Gujarat")]
                    ,className="dropdown")

def graph1_convicts():
    return dcc.Graph(id="graph1_convicts")

def graph2_convicts():
    return dcc.Graph(id="graph2_convicts")

def graph1_under_trial():
    return dcc.Graph(id="graph1_under_trial")

def graph2_under_trial():
    return dcc.Graph(id="graph2_under_trial")

def graph1_detenues():
    return dcc.Graph(id="graph1_detenues")

def graph2_detenues():
    return dcc.Graph(id="graph2_detenues")
```

Layout

```
app.layout = dbc.Container([
                            dbc.Row([dbc.Col([html.Div("Indian Prison Stats between 2001-2013", className="heading")])]),
                            dbc.Row([dbc.Col(dropdown())]),
                            dcc.Tabs(id="tabs-selector",
                                     value="tab-1",
                                     className="custom-tabs-container",
                                     children=[
                                                dcc.Tab(label="Convicts",
                                                        value="tab-1",
                                                        className="custom-tab",
                                                        children=[html.Div([graph1_convicts(),
                                                                            html.Br(),
                                                                            graph2_convicts()]),
                                                                  ]),
                                                dcc.Tab(label="under_trial",
                                                        value="tab-2",
                                                        className="custom-tab",
                                                        children=[html.Div([graph1_under_trial(),
                                                                            html.Br(),
                                                                            graph2_under_trial()]),
                                                                  ]),
                                                dcc.Tab(label="detenues",
                                                        value="tab-3",
                                                        className="custom-tab",
                                                        children=[html.Div([graph1_detenues(),
                                                                            html.Br(),
                                                                            graph2_detenues()]),
                                                                  ]),
                                     ]),
])
```

Callback

```
@app.callback([Output('graph1_convicts', 'figure'),
               Output('graph2_convicts', 'figure'),
               Output("graph1_under_trial", "figure"),
               Output("graph2_under_trial", "figure"),
               Output("graph1_detenues", "figure"),
               Output("graph2_detenues", "figure")],
              [Input('dropdown', 'value'),
               Input("tabs-selector", "value")])

def update_graph(dropdown, tab):
    # df1_convicts has only convicts column kept, rest all removed, and groupby is done on gender column
    df1_convicts = df[df["state_name"]==dropdown]
    df1_convicts = df1_convicts.drop(["is_state", "caste", "under_trial", "detenues", "others"], axis=1)
    df1_convicts = df1_convicts.groupby(['state_name', "year", "gender"])['convicts'].sum().reset_index()

    # df2_convicts has only convicts column kept, rest all removed, and groupby is done on caste column
    df2_convicts = df[df["state_name"]==dropdown]
    df2_convicts = df2_convicts.drop(["is_state", "gender", "under_trial", "detenues", "others"], axis=1)
    df2_convicts = df2_convicts.groupby(["state_name", "year", "caste"])["convicts"].sum().reset_index()

    # df1_under_trial has only under_trial column kept, rest all removed, and groupby is done on gender column
    df1_under_trial = df[df["state_name"]==dropdown]
    df1_under_trial = df1_under_trial.drop(["is_state", "caste", "convicts", "detenues", "others"], axis=1)
    df1_under_trial = df1_under_trial.groupby(['state_name', "year", "gender"])['under_trial'].sum().reset_index()

    # df2_under_trial has only under_trial column kept, rest all removed, and groupby is done on caste column
    df2_under_trial = df[df["state_name"]==dropdown]
    df2_under_trial = df2_under_trial.drop(["is_state", "gender", "convicts", "detenues", "others"], axis=1)
    df2_under_trial = df2_under_trial.groupby(["state_name", "year", "caste"])["under_trial"].sum().reset_index()

    # df1_detenues has only detenues column kept, rest all removed, and groupby is done on gender column
    df1_detenues = df[df["state_name"]==dropdown]
    df1_detenues = df1_detenues.drop(["is_state", "caste", "convicts", "under_trial", "others"], axis=1)
    df1_detenues = df1_detenues.groupby(['state_name', "year", "gender"])['detenues'].sum().reset_index()

    # df2_under_trial has only under_trial column kept, rest all removed, and groupby is done on caste column
    df2_detenues = df[df["state_name"]==dropdown]
    df2_detenues = df2_detenues.drop(["is_state", "gender", "convicts", "under_trial", "others"], axis=1)
    df2_detenues = df2_detenues.groupby(["state_name", "year", "caste"])["detenues"].sum().reset_index()


    fig1_convicts = px.bar(df1_convicts, x="year", y="convicts", color="gender", title="gender distribution of convicts",
                            color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Set1, opacity=0.6)
    fig2_convicts = px.bar(df2_convicts, x="year", y="convicts", color="caste", title="caste distribution of convicts",
                            color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Set1, opacity=0.6)

    fig1_under_trial = px.bar(df1_under_trial, x="year", y="under_trial", color="gender", title="gender distribution of under_trial",
                                color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Set1, opacity=0.6)
    fig2_under_trial = px.bar(df2_under_trial, x="year", y="under_trial", color="caste", title="caste distribution of under_trial",
                                color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Set1, opacity=0.6)

    fig1_detenues = px.bar(df1_detenues, x="year", y="detenues", color="gender", title="gender distribution of detenues",
                            color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Set1, opacity=0.6)
    fig2_detenues = px.bar(df2_detenues, x="year", y="detenues", color="caste", title="caste distribution of detenues",
                            color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Set1, opacity=0.6)

    if tab=="tab-1":
        return fig1_convicts, fig2_convicts
    elif tab=="tab-3":
        return fig1_detenues, fig2_detenues
    elif tab=="tab-2":
        return fig1_under_trial, fig2_under_trial


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=5050)
```

How do I define the callback?
I could easily create gender and caste distribution of either convicts or under_trial or detenues. But, I am confused about how to show all 6 graphs under the 3 tabs based on the dropdown value.
I searched online and found that dcc.State might be useful in this case, but I couldn't understand it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing is that you need to return all the output you define in the callback.

in your case you need 6 outputs to this callback

now as I see it you have 2 options:

1. generate all the graphs when you change the dropdown it will work with the current  contact layout
2. only hold 1 tab contact and dynamically create only 2 graph when you switch tabs

option 1 code should look like this:

```
@app.callback([Output('graph1_convicts', 'figure'),
               Output('graph2_convicts', 'figure'),
               Output("graph1_under_trial", "figure"),
               Output("graph2_under_trial", "figure"),
               Output("graph1_detenues", "figure"),
               Output("graph2_detenues", "figure")],
              [Input('dropdown', 'value')])

def update_graph(dropdown):
    # df1_convicts has only convicts column kept, rest all removed, and groupby is done on gender column
    df1_convicts = df[df["state_name"]==dropdown]
    df1_convicts = df1_convicts.drop(["is_state", "caste", "under_trial", "detenues", "others"], axis=1)
    df1_convicts = df1_convicts.groupby(['state_name', "year", "gender"])['convicts'].sum().reset_index()

    # df2_convicts has only convicts column kept, rest all removed, and groupby is done on caste column
    df2_convicts = df[df["state_name"]==dropdown]
    df2_convicts = df2_convicts.drop(["is_state", "gender", "under_trial", "detenues", "others"], axis=1)
    df2_convicts = df2_convicts.groupby(["state_name", "year", "caste"])["convicts"].sum().reset_index()

    # df1_under_trial has only under_trial column kept, rest all removed, and groupby is done on gender column
    df1_under_trial = df[df["state_name"]==dropdown]
    df1_under_trial = df1_under_trial.drop(["is_state", "caste", "convicts", "detenues", "others"], axis=1)
    df1_under_trial = df1_under_trial.groupby(['state_name', "year", "gender"])['under_trial'].sum().reset_index()

    # df2_under_trial has only under_trial column kept, rest all removed, and groupby is done on caste column
    df2_under_trial = df[df["state_name"]==dropdown]
    df2_under_trial = df2_under_trial.drop(["is_state", "gender", "convicts", "detenues", "others"], axis=1)
    df2_under_trial = df2_under_trial.groupby(["state_name", "year", "caste"])["under_trial"].sum().reset_index()

    # df1_detenues has only detenues column kept, rest all removed, and groupby is done on gender column
    df1_detenues = df[df["state_name"]==dropdown]
    df1_detenues = df1_detenues.drop(["is_state", "caste", "convicts", "under_trial", "others"], axis=1)
    df1_detenues = df1_detenues.groupby(['state_name', "year", "gender"])['detenues'].sum().reset_index()

    # df2_under_trial has only under_trial column kept, rest all removed, and groupby is done on caste column
    df2_detenues = df[df["state_name"]==dropdown]
    df2_detenues = df2_detenues.drop(["is_state", "gender", "convicts", "under_trial", "others"], axis=1)
    df2_detenues = df2_detenues.groupby(["state_name", "year", "caste"])["detenues"].sum().reset_index()


    fig1_convicts = px.bar(df1_convicts, x="year", y="convicts", color="gender", title="gender distribution of convicts",
                            color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Set1, opacity=0.6)
    fig2_convicts = px.bar(df2_convicts, x="year", y="convicts", color="caste", title="caste distribution of convicts",
                            color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Set1, opacity=0.6)

    fig1_under_trial = px.bar(df1_under_trial, x="year", y="under_trial", color="gender", title="gender distribution of under_trial",
                                color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Set1, opacity=0.6)
    fig2_under_trial = px.bar(df2_under_trial, x="year", y="under_trial", color="caste", title="caste distribution of under_trial",
                                color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Set1, opacity=0.6)

    fig1_detenues = px.bar(df1_detenues, x="year", y="detenues", color="gender", title="gender distribution of detenues",
                            color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Set1, opacity=0.6)
    fig2_detenues = px.bar(df2_detenues, x="year", y="detenues", color="caste", title="caste distribution of detenues",
                            color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Set1, opacity=0.6)

        return fig1_convicts, fig2_convicts,
               fig1_under_trial, fig2_under_trial,
               fig1_detenues, fig2_detenues
```

for option 2 you can see https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/tabs it is the first option in the examples

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.Got the graphs working under the tabs using dcc.Store.